# How to draw sections in view?

Tags: android, android-layout

Please help me in the following.
How to divide vertical layout by sections like on the picture http://developer.android.com/design/media/metrics_forms.png ?  Its not a ListView, I have just layout with sets of text and editview. I just need to divide it so it looks nicer. Hot to draw it?

Also how to make so EditText looks like input on the picture?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for Android Holo Theme,  Please check **[Useful link for generating nine patch images &  res drawables and styles for Holo Theme](http://android-holo-colors.com/)**

You can use LinearLayout with vertical orientation, for spacing between the components create one common xml and include it wherever required in your layout.

Comment: thanks for idea to use layout like a spacer. Will try to apply Theme to my app.